# setInterval won't repeat?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

why has this been associated with the above? I read through those answers after understanding the issue from answers provided below and there's nothing in the above that would have generated any insight.

**html doc**

```js
let tester = 0;
    setInterval(iterateCounter(), 1000);
    
    function iterateCounter(){
      ++ tester;
      console.log(tester);
    }
```

this is probably a horrible question but i've checked MDN, JSinfo, and perused stack for about 20 minutes on top of that. Why is this code snippet running once and then not repeating?

Comment: Plenty of dupes on this.... () executes it and what is returned is assigned to the interval. In your case you have `setInterval(undefined, 1000);`

Comment: @epascarello non-specific and unhelpful given A) you didn't reference anything specifically B) the question was already answered C) you offered a code snippet that only makes sense to someone who understood the problem a priori.

Comment: And your selected answer does NOTHING to explain why.

Comment: @epascarello pragmatic > pedantic, the answer below it explains why perfectly explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only pass the function name instead of calling it:

```js
let tester = 0;
setInterval(iterateCounter, 1000);
    
function iterateCounter(){
      ++ tester;
      console.log(tester);
}
```

For more info, you can check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` in its first argument accepts function itself, not what function returns. To make it work simply remove scopes after `iterateCounter`

```js
let tester = 0;
    setInterval(iterateCounter, 1000);
    
    function iterateCounter(){
      ++ tester;
      console.log(tester);
    }
```